# Is it legal to check the number of resources in the bank?

Tags: catan

Could a player, during their turn, count the number of resources of each kind in the bank? I would typically do this before playing a monopoly card for instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only count resource cards after rolling, to determine if there are enough for everyone to get the cards they need.

From the [official FAQ](https://www.catan.com/faqs/92?page=2):

> Resource Cards - May I count the Resource Cards in the supply stacks during play?
>
> > Yes, immediately after a production roll, before distributing the resources - but only if it isn't sure whether there will be enough cards for all players entitled to receive them.

Comment: This answer surprised me; we always used to count the resource piles to determine what would be a good resource for Monopoly. It’s impossible to prevent you from eyeballing the piles to see which ones are lower, though.

Comment: In almost every game, I just house rule that information that was ever public stays public. For Catan, that means that since it is always publicly known when resources enter or leave the bank, it should be publicly known how much is left (and hence players can count).

Comment: @BenjaminCosman While I understand the reasons for that; I also think it's fine for memory/tracking to be one of the skills that a board game puts to the test.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman wouldn't that imply that a player's hand is also public, since you know everything they've received, discarded, and spent?  even trades are generally discussed publicly

Comment: "only if it isn't sure whether there will be enough cards for all players entitled to receive them" - For this to be possible then "looking" at the pile is ok. Just don't pick it up and go through it. It is easy enough to see if a pile is nearly empty assuming the pile is somewhere around the table. I think this is an important point, but not worth its own answer.

Comment: @Eevee My group has sometimes gone either way on that one - trades can be semi-private, and stealing effects (e.g. the robber) are entirely private unless the players want to discuss what was stolen. When we have made hands public, it hasn't felt like it makes a big difference.

Comment: @GendoIkari I agree, but I'm also not very interested in memory tests, so if it's easy to remove one I often will and focus more on the other skills being tested. I'm not saying this is the *right* or *only* way to play, just the way I prefer :)  Also, memory components often hit new players especially hard, since they don't know what they should be tracking and have too much new stuff on their minds anyway. I'm fine with new players losing, but I'd prefer they leave thinking "Look at all those strategic considerations unique to this game" rather than "I lost because of memory. Again."

Comment: @BenjaminCosman In many games victory points are scored publicly but then are hidden. This is done so that people do not gang up on the leader making a less interesting game. Those games work poorly, if this information remains un-hidden

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh It depends on who you're playing with - if e.g. the result of keeping the points hidden is that players a) waste time and effort memorizing points as they come in and then still ganging up on the leader, or b) argue a lot over who's the leader, then pick someone (possibly incorrectly) and gang up on them anyway, then you're still better off keeping the information un-hidden. And for me, if the game is designed such that ganging up on the leader is both possible and makes the game not fun, then I probably won't like the game anyway regardless of if points are hidden.